# What is wrong with this SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I've spend good hours trying to fix this one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `users`
WHERE  `IP` = `123.231.213.132`
```

What is wrong with this?

```
#1054 - Unknown column '123.231.213.132' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should not use backticks with column values. you have to use either single or double quotes otherwise mysql will consider that value as a column name.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `users`
WHERE  `IP` = '123.231.213.132'
```

Answer (score 7):

Use **single quotes** rather than backtick characters for ``` `123.231.213.132`` ```

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `users`
WHERE  `IP` = '123.231.213.132'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use quotes ' not backticks ` for string literals

Answer (score 2):

What's with the backticks? Use single quotes
Also I'm assuming that users is a table name and IP is an entity of users.

Also...you have to end your statement with a semi-colon

Answer (score 1):

It might be the single speach mark symbol.  Try replacing them manually.

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong quotation characters

to specify string value in mysql statement you have to use either '(single quote) or "(double quote)

`(backtick) characters are used to explicitly specify that quoted string represents a field name from where mysql should get the data

backticks are required in your statements if column names are conflicting with mysql's reserved keywords like `index`, `where`, etc